# Get String attribute in SCNText

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have an SCNText element:

```
print(NodeElement?.geometry?)

// output
`Optional(<SCNText: 0x1c01f6800 'text' | 3 elements | string=At desk extrusionDepth=0.500> )`
```

However, when I do:

`print(self.editingSCNBodyNode?.geometry?.string)`

I get the error:

`Value of type 'SCNGeometry' has no member 'string'`

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntext/1523439-string), this is variable can be gotten & set.

Answer (score 3):

`SCNText` is a subclass of `SCNGeometry`. The type of 
`self.editingSCNBodyNode?.geometry` is `SCNGeometry?` and you have
to conditionally downcast it:

```
if let scnText = self.editingSCNBodyNode?.geometry as? SCNText {
    print(scnText.string)
}
```